# Kotlin annotation as generic function parameter

Tags: generics, annotations, kotlin, instanceof

I'm wondering if there is any way to use an annotation as a type parameter for a generic and determine the instance of the provided input? Essentially, I want to allow only objects that make use of a particular annotation to be accepted by a method and use type casting to determine the underlying type.

I tried marking the generic type with the annotation but when I try to cast model I get an error: "Incompatible types: UsesAnnotation and MyAnnotation"

This makes sense, since I'm not extending MyAnnotation, I'm just marking UsesAnnotation by it. But is there a way to make this work? I just want to limit the inputs to instances that make use of the annotation and then figure out the type that was provided as an input.

The annotation:

```
@MustBeDocumented
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class MyAnnotation
```

Abstract Factory:

```
abstract class MyFactory<in t: Any> {
   ...
   abstract fun genericMethod(model: T): Int
   ...
}
```

Its subclass:

```
class MyFactoryImplementation<MyAnnotationType> {
   ...
   override fun genericMethod(model: MyAnnotation): Int {
      return when (model) {
         is UsesAnnotation -> 1
         else -> 0
   }
   ...
}
```

The annotated class:

```
@MyAnnotation
class UsesAnnotation
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. First thing you shoud consider — annotations can't be inherited
2. On the other hand it's perfectly possible to determine if anything is annotated with annotation with `RUNTIME` retention. For this to work you need to add `kotlin-reflect` to your classpath.

   ```
   inline fun <reified T : Any> isAnnotatedWith(t: T, annotationClass: KClass<*>) = 
       isAnnotated(t::class, annotationClass)

   fun isAnnotated(inputClass: KClass<*>, annotationClass: KClass<*>) = 
       inputClass.annotations.any { it.annotationClass == annotationClass }
   ```

You can pass instance of your annotation into function `isAnnotatedWith` from code above and get result.